# In agile development team, is it helpful to also have a minority of developers who may not be agile?

Tags: agile, scrum

We have a few developers who are slower than the typical agile expectation. They get fewer tickets completed in a given sprint. But on the upside, their work is more correct and higher quality.

Is this expected in an agile team, where you always get a few that is slower?

Comment: No, but if it works for your team, then that's OK. Agile is a general approach, not a set of rigid commands.

Comment: Agile doesn't even figure into this equation. Any team, any development methodology, and you will find fast and slow developers. That's life.

Comment: "In an agile team, is it helpful to have a majority of developers who are rushing out low-quality, bug-ridden code?"

Comment: *slower than ...  expectation*. So the expectation is not user happiness with *working* functionality?.  True anacdote: Joe was *the* programmer that management told us to be like. He is the most productive on the team!  I got to fix some of his code that failed acceptance testing.  It took me two weeks. The difference?  My fix worked, did not break existing code, did not hold up the release failing layers of testing, and got into production. The later any given bug is fixed (or prevented) the more expensive - studies and experience have proven this for many decades now.

Comment: And to add to what @radarbob posted, when you hear, "Joe is great! He's always fixing problems!"  Eventually someone catches on and figures out, "Hey, Joe is always *creating* problems.  That he then has to fix..."  Don't be Joe - Joe ain't a rock star, Joe's just a rock.  (As in, "As smart as...")

Comment: *"on the upside, their work is more correct and higher quality."* - actually, that situation seems to be uninteresting, because it describing a balanced situation. The more interesting case is when you have members in your team who are slower *and* producing lower quality work than the average (maybe they are slower *because* of lower quality, tickets not completed in time because of more bugs and rejected pull requests).

Comment: I would take *'more correct and higher quality but slower'* over *'fast and buggy'* always.

Answer (score 8):

This question is based on a false premise. An individual on a team is not "agile" or "not agile". Agility isn't about being fast in completing units of work, it refers to the ability of the team or organization to respond to changes in a highly uncertain or ambiguous environment.

On a team, different people do indeed work at different rates. There are lots of factors. It could be related to things like familiarity with the tools and technology, familiarity with the codebase, the ability to focus, the ability to get questions answered if things come up, and others. Without a good understanding of the team and the team's dynamics, I really can't get into specifics.

However, I will add that having "more correct and higher quality" work is usually faster. This is something that has been known for a long time and is at the heart of Lean methodologies. Building quality in from the beginning reduces the waste associated with downstream inspection and test activities. If you have people who are progressing work downstream with defects, they are probably getting less value-added work done than the people doing higher quality work the first time, in the long run.

Comment: *progressing work downstream with defects, they are probably getting less value-added work done*    Amen, brothers and sisters! I've noticed that the later defects are found the earlier the defects were introduced. Consequently, production bug fixes tend to be hack jobs, getting hacky-er over time. If the now fatal flaws are not addressed ( Not! It's production! ) eventually maintenance can devolve to a bug-inducing-bug-fix, non-value added, feedback loop. The deepest cut of all was the customer head guy telling me: "we don't report bugs any more because we know they'll never get fixed."

Answer (score 3):

> We have a few developers who are slower than the typical agile expectation. They get fewer tickets completed in a given sprint.

That doesn't mean they aren't agile. No two people on a team will work at the same speed. In agile software development, "agile" refers to the whole team rather than individuals. Either the whole team is agile or it's not.

In fact, you could argue that every team *needs* some who are slower. They bring a different perspective. For example, they may complete fewer points because they write more tests, or work on harder problems, or who write more documentation, or any number of other reasons.

> But on the upside, their work is more correct and higher quality.

Higher quality work? Why wouldn't you want as much of that as you could get?

Agile isn't about speed *per se*. It's a development model that attempts to make sure you're building the right product with the appropriate quality, in a sustainable manner, with course corrections early and often.

> Is this expected in an agile team, where you always get a few that is slower?

Absolutely, yes.

Comment: "Agile isn't about speed per se." – Really, the only thing agile has to do with speed *at all* is that it requires fast feedback loops.

Answer (score 2):

Agile development is not a race. Finishing tickets is a rubbish measurement when these finished tickets then all get flagged up in QA or worse, lead to customer complaints. Same if rushed tickets lead to code that's a maintenance nightmare.

With your comment "They get fewer tickets completed in a given sprint. But on the upside, their work is more correct and higher quality." it seems that someone thinks that completing more tickets incorrectly and in lower quality is actually a good thing. It isn't.

To answer your question, agile development is not related to speed.

And if you don't want to end up with a codebase that will actively slow your team down, look for more quality in your development.